# DELETE API not working

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, http-delete

I want to simply delete a user from the database. using MEAN Stack, mlab.

This is my delete API

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { 
        return res.status(500).send("There was a penter code hereroblem deleting the user.");
    } else {
        res.status(200).send("User "+ user.username +" was deleted.");
        res.json({ user: user });
    }
    });
});
```

this is the service i am calling

```
deleteUser(_id){
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.delete(this.deleteurl+this._id)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

my HTML Delete Button

```
button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteUser(_id)">Delete User</button>
```

and this is the `deleteuser` function I am calling on the button in HTML

```
deleteUser(_id){
    this.authService.deleteUser('localhost:3000/users/delete'+'/'+_id).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data,"data from db")
      this.user();
    },
    err => {
      console.error(err, "error" )
    }
  )};
```

Currently, I am putting the id as the id number of my document, i.e. hardcode the value of `id`

and this is the error I am getting

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/delete/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Just log the error and check your server logs

Comment: Your `deleteUser` method should use `this.deleteurl + _id` (not `this._id`).

Comment: i just made these changes the console result is still the same P.S. the error got somewhat like this 

**DELETE localhost:3000/users/delete/localhost:3000/users/delete/… 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: why the http://localhost:3000 ??? use only /users/delete and see if it will work

Comment: this.authService.deleteUser('/users/delete'+'/'+_id)

Answer (score 0):

In your `deleteUser` function your not accessing the function parameter, but you try to access a local variable with the `this` operator. This variable is not existing, which is why you get an undefined in the link.

Remove the `this` part, so that the function parameter is used with the url instead.

```
deleteUser(_id){
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.delete(this.deleteurl+_id)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: i just made these changes
the console result is still same

P.S. the error got somewhat like this


** DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/delete/localhost:3000/users/delete/undefined 404 (Not Found) **

Comment: I just notice that you have two `deleteUser` functions, one in the service and one in the component. The problem with the `this` operator is in the service. Also in this service function you are expecting the ID to delete, nothing more, but you're currently giving the full link *plus* the id. Try to call the service function with `this.authService.deleteUser(_id).subscribe`

Comment: Changes Updated:

I changed the button function to this so it will help to distinguish

`OnDeleteUser(_id){
    this.authService.deleteUser(_id).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data,"data from db")
      this.user();
    },
    err => {
      console.error(err, "error" )
    }`

and service deleteUser function to

`deleteUser(_id){
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.delete(this.deleteurl+_id)
    .map(res => res.json());
}`

and this is what i am passing in the component.ts file 

_id:'5a3aaa1da685361dccddbbad';

Comment: alright, still errors from the function call? I'm pretty sure the output should be different after these changes

Comment: ** DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/delete/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error) ** 

The error is different now 
but it is there :-/

Comment: You're calling your `OnDeleteUser` function from your button. You're giving an _id parameter to this function call: `(click)="deleteUser(_id)"`. Where do you get this _id from? is your button inside a table or a list? You can test if this _id is not correctly used by putting a `console.log(_id)` right at the beginning of your `OnDeleteUser` function. If it's already undefined there, than you are not using a correct variable inside your button `click` function. Can you update your code by adding additional html code from your button to see where the _id comes from?

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal Server error coming from these line.

```
User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { 

    return res.status(500).send("There was a penter code hereroblem deleting the user.");


}
```